# Globalization and Localization in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

I am having application hosted on one of my client located in India,also the branch of my client is in U.S, they access the same application from india.

**Scenario**

When any employee of india make an entry through forms the timestamp and date of India is been updated in the database
Also at same time when any employee make an entry from U.S. timestamp and date is updated according to us cultureinfo, what we need is when employee from U.S. site updates the data timestamp and date of India should be updated in the database.

Comment: Please add the timestamp code.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you should store all date and time in [UTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx), and then display it accordingly using user [time zone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.tolocaltime.aspx).

Comment: Everything is pretty much in MSDN links in my answer.